# Jupyter notebook launch results in Exit code 1

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spyder

Whenever I try to launch Spyder or Jupyter notebook from Anaconda Navigator it returns `Exit code: 1`. I tried to set paths and upgrade packages, but nothing works.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

[image: image1]

### Details

- Windows 8
- Jupyter Notebook v6.4.5
- Spyder v5.1.5

Comment: Please review [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)